# Can't get return value from async waterfall in node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, promise

I have a node module I made that performs some operations using async waterfall. It works standalone, and completes all the tasks when run through an AJAX call, however, my AJAX callback never gets its return value.

```
//node module 

var boilerplateFn = function(params){
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            //do task 1
            callback(null, results);
        },
        function(results, callback){
            //task 2 is write
            fs.writeFile(path, results, function(err){
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    callback(null, results)
                }
            })
        }
    ], function(err, results){
        return results
    });
}

module.exports = exports = boilerplateFn;
```

This writes the file correctly, and if I do a console.log in the final function, I can see my results string.

However when I try to include it in a route like this:

```
var components = require('./app/js/node_components');
app.get('/process/:scale/:type', function(req, res){
    var data = processRequest(req.params);
    res.json(data);
});

function processRequest(params){
    console.log(componentents.boilerplateFn(params)) //prints undefined in Terminal
    return {
        result: componentents.boilerplateFn(params);
    }
}
```

and I make a call to the route through a jQuery AJAX request, the file is written fine, however, I don't see the returned data printed in the console like I'd expect:

```
return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/' + paramStr,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('returned data', data) //returned data Object{}
    }).fail(function(jqObj, textStatus, err){
        console.log(jqObj, textStatus, err);
    })
});
```

I assume this means that my file is writing but that my function has already returned so it never gets the returned text. However, I tried wrapping `res.json` in a callback, but it didn't change anything.

```
    processRequest(req.params, function(data){
      res.json(data);
    });


function processRequest(params, callback){
    var data = componentents.boilerplateFn(params);
    callback(data);
}
```

Not really surprised it didn't work, just was an idea. How can I get my returned value back to the function that calls the module? Or have I just done something fundamentally incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't treat something that is asynchronous as if it is synchronous. Instead, pass in a callback:

```
var boilerplateFn = function(params, cb) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      // do task 1
      callback(null, results);
    },
    function(results, callback) {
      // task 2 is write
      fs.writeFile(path, results, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        } else {
          callback(null, results);
        }
      })
    }
  ], cb);
}

module.exports = boilerplateFn;
```

Then use it like:

```
var components = require('./app/js/node_components');
app.get('/process/:scale/:type', function(req, res) {
  processRequest(req.params, function(err, data) {
    // TODO: check `err` first
    res.json({ result: data });
  });
});

function processRequest(params, cb) {
  components.boilerplateFn(params, cb);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. In this callback `cessRequest(req.params, function(err, data) {`, where do the parameters `err` and `data` come from. How does async know to pass them on to this function when it was just referenced in the last line with `], cb);`, no `(err, data)` or anything.

Comment: Those arguments come from the "final" callback (the one that gets called after all of your "waterfalled" functions complete) of `async.waterfall()` which passes those two values in.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the same thing again here :

```
function processRequest(params, callback){
    var data = componentents.boilerplateFn(params); //this writes undefined to data 
    callback(data);
}
```

simplest solution is to call the function directly in the .get request, don't overdesign

```
var components = require('./app/js/node_components');
app.get('/process/:scale/:type', function(req, res){
    componentents.boilerplateFn(req.params, function(err, results){
        if (err){
           //handle error
        }else{
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});



var boilerplateFn = function(params, cb){
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        //do task 1
        callback(null, results);
    },
    function(results, callback){
        //task 2 is write
        fs.writeFile(path, results, function(err){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                callback(null, results)
            }
        })
    }
], cb);
}

module.exports = exports = boilerplateFn;
```